Site baseUrl with locale and entry URI matching
Consider the following. I have two sites:

site: the main site
site_de: the German version of the site

Those two sites have the following Base URLs:

https://my.site.test
https://my.site.test/de

I have a Pages section that is available in both sites, with Entry URIs that look like this:

{slug}
{slug}

I want all requests to end up in my main index template, which will load up the entry requested, making entry available in it. So there's only a single templates/index.twig and a single web/index.php, no subfolders or duplicates, and I'd like to keep it that way, to keep things DRY.
Linking to other parts of the site can be done using siteUrl('foo/bar') which results in:

https://my.site.test/foo/bar
https://my.site.test/de/foo/bar

...respectively. This is good.
For a Pages entry 'About us', these entry URLs are generated:

https://my.site.test/about-us
https://my.site.test/de/about-us

The issue here is that the German URL will trigger a 404, as Craft will try and match the entry with the URI de/about-us, which does not exist; about-us is stored in the DB.
If I change the settings to the Base URLs both pointing to https://my.site.test and then the German entry URI to de/{slug}, the German URL will work. But pointing to siteUrl('foo/bar') will point to the main site, without /de in there.
In conclusion
Is there a way to have both? So, keep /de in the Base URL (as it is the base of that site), but have it match de/about-us too without having to define the country code in the Entry URI?
Side note, I have a custom module in place that changes the default site based on the incoming URI.

I've tested a site with a similar setup that I have and for me it works fine - my base URL in settings for the second site includes the country code, while the first site has none. Then using a single shared template for both sites and using siteUrl() in there includes the country code on the second site but not on the first. Maybe something to do with your custom module??

@JamesSmith what does your section's entry URI format look like? In the above setup, the siteUrl() works as expected, but entry URLs throw 404s unless I add the country code in the entry URI format, which I'm hoping to avoid.

The Entry URI Formats for both sites are the same as each other: in this case resources/{slug}. One other difference might be my template routing - for which I've set up a symlink at templates/de pointing to templates/default - however that's not necessary if you just put all your templates at the root of templates instead of in site-specific sub-directories. (Also, I'm checking this in Craft 4)

FWIW, disabling the module makes no difference. I'm using Craft 5.

@Low FWIW, the way you've set this up should work out of the box – i.e. Craft should set the current site based on the incoming URL and there shouldn't be a need for that custom module, multiple index.php files (that hasn't been required since Craft 3.0), symlinks or any other hacks. So if that German URL 404s, something is wrong somewhere :)

@Low Shot in the dark, but are you potentially overriding the current site URL with a CRAFT_WEB_URL variable in your .env file? If that's the case, try removing that.

Okay, the issue had to do with Craft not being able to match the URLs to the right site.
I have been using custom aliases to define the site URLs, like this:

@siteOrigin
@siteOrigin/de

...but defined the aliases in the init() method of the custom module. Apparently, that meant the aliases weren't available yet when the Request was handled, therefore always defaulting back to the main site.
I moved defining the aliases to config/general.php using a static method in the module, effectively making the aliases available earlier in the (cough) “parse order”.
